# Cannot create an Entities object, but can access generated classes - why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I can create objects of each table in my database, so the .edmx file is doing it's job.

Why can't I create a new dbEntEntities (intellisense only pops up dbNull) object of the .edmx file?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean you can't create one? Is the type not found or is an Exception being thrown when you try to instantiate one?

Comment: The type isn't found at all. Intellisense only shows me DBNull when I start typing db, and I tried typing it in manually and try to automatically reference something I needed using Ctrl + . but it still wouldn't work. I'm confused. The same thing happens if I try to use L2S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have changed the name of the Entity Container and not have realized it. Open your Entity Diagram, find the Entity Container in the Model Browser and view its properties to see its name.

You may have also created your Entities in a separate namespace. If that's the case, make sure you include that namespace in the `using` statements at the top of your code file.

A little more detail about your problem (which file you're trying to instantiate your Entity Container in, etc.) would be helpful.

Comment: I'll edit my question, I cannot create a 'Entities' object. I mixed the two up, however the problem is still there.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia - What do you mean you can't create one? Is the type not found or is an Exception being thrown when you try to instantiate one?